# Como faço para guardar uma string com tamanho indefinido numa estrutura?

Tags: c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Ecoponto{
   int codigo;
   int contentores[3];
   char cidade[20];
   char *rua;
   int nporta;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   struct Ecoponto ecoponto;
   printf("\nIntroduza o nome da rua:");
   scanf("%s",ecoponto.rua);
   printf("%s",&ecoponto.rua);



   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Gostava de saber qual é a melhor maneira de guardar "o nome da rua" com um tamanho desconhecido na estrutura "Ecoponto ecoponto".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para guardar uma string de tamanho desconhecido, sem gastar memória extra, você precisa ler o nome da rua em um buffer, uma variável bem grande que pode suportar qualquer nome de rua, por exemplo, tamanho 1000. Depois usar a biblioteca string.h e a sua função strlen(), que retorna quantos caracteres tem uma string e usar strlen(buffer).

Agora você sabe quantos caracteres tem o nome da rua, se você fizer

```
char buffer[1000]; 
scanf("%s", buffer);
int a = strlen(buffer);
```

Você vai poder usar a função malloc() da biblioteca stdlib.h para armazenar quanto de memória você precisa, por exemplo:

```
char *nome_rua = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*a);
```

Depois, você pode copiar o conteudo do buffer para a sua variável, podendo fazer o uso da função strcpy() da biblioteca string.h

Fonte: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/string_h.htm

Você precisa dar malloc em (a+1) posições, porque a string tem obrigatoriamente o \O, que delimita o seu fim.

E também, você pode usar a função

```
char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
```

Porque ai você copiaria apenas do buffer apenas a quantidade de caracteres lidos.

Comment: Mas ao usar buffer[1000] não estou a limitar o tamanho da string para 1000?

Comment: Bem, você pode colocar o tamanho desse buffer bem grande, por exemplo, 10000. Ou ir lendo char por char, guardando em uma variável auxiliar (de maneira parecida) e controlando quantos char's foram lidos para alocar somente o necessário

Comment: Permitir uma entrada ilimitada não é uma boa ideia. Se alguém quiser travar sua aplicação, vai conseguir facilmente.

Comment: Outra dúvida como é que passo depois o buffer para "ecoponto.rua" tentei com o strcpy e não deu e eu acho que é por a rua estar como apontador num estrutura.

Comment: É que se for provavelmente um trabalho escolar, pode ser escolhido um valor aleatório (mas, finito). E pode ser um teste você pensar nesse caso.

Comment: Obrigado.Já consegui por a dar mas quando dou um espaço entre as palavras só copia a 1º palavra.

Comment: Estáva 'scanf("%s",buffer);' mas dessa maneira ele já não copia para a "rua".

Comment: Faltava o % no scanf("%[^\n]s",buffer); já está a dar direito obrigado.